# unable to start glass fish server from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-4

Glassfish is starting properly from command prompt,but when i start in eclipse it is giving following errors

```
2015-01-28T18:16:08.193+0530|Info: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89)
2015-01-28T18:16:08.198+0530|Info: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2015-01-28T18:16:08.647+0530|Info: SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-01-28T18:16:08.660+0530|Info: SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-01-28T18:16:08.676+0530|Info: SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
2015-01-28T18:16:09.817+0530|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 50ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,181]
2015-01-28T18:16:09.847+0530|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 10ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4,848]
2015-01-28T18:16:10.117+0530|Info: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
2015-01-28T18:16:10.221+0530|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3,700]
2015-01-28T18:16:10.236+0530|Info: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2015-01-28T18:16:10.959+0530|Info: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (89) startup time : Felix (16,260ms), startup services(2,966ms), total(19,226ms)
2015-01-28T18:16:10.964+0530|Severe: Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:450)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:439)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.start(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.start(GlassfishNetworkListener.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start(GrizzlyProxy.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:470)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:393)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:281)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:328)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:448)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:163)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2204)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:673)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:660)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneJob.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:490)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpAllTheWay.go(CurrentTaskFuture.java:362)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpAllTheWay.access$100(CurrentTaskFuture.java:279)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture.go(CurrentTaskFuture.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.proceedTo(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.RunLevelControllerImpl.proceedTo(RunLevelControllerImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.proceedTo(AppServerStartup.java:532)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:329)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:217)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishDecorator.start(GlassFishDecorator.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.start(EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl.java:75)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishDecorator.start(GlassFishDecorator.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishImpl.start(OSGiGlassFishImpl.java:71)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)

2015-01-28T18:16:11.044+0530|Info: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
2015-01-28T18:16:11.981+0530|Info: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
2015-01-28T18:16:12.044+0530|Info: Server shutdown initiated
2015-01-28T18:16:12.049+0530|Info: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@18066dc as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@3afdcc.
2015-01-28T18:16:13.102+0530|Info: Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@18066dc from service registry.
```

i have even changed port number from 8080 to 9090 but there is no improvement
localhost:4848 is open admin console without any problem

Comment: The description is very clear something is using the address already. So start eclipse telnet into the address and have a look. You can also use other networking tools such as netstat to see which ports are being used.